# Remove decimal values using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having following values in database table :

```
12.00
15.00
18.00
20.00
```

I want to remove all decimal ZEROS from all values , So how can I do this using SQL query. I tried replace query but that is not working.

I want values like :

```
12
15
18
20
```

My replace query :

```
       select height(replace (12.00, '')) from table;
```

Please help.

Comment: What data type is the column set to?

Comment: @ivan.sivak - That is decimal.

Comment: Leave them as they are and manipulate on retrieval `SELECT FLOOR(col) FROM t`

Comment: `SELECT COPNVERT(INT,YourColumn) FROM YourTable`

Comment: replace should have worked if you did it correctly.   You should post your attempt.

Comment: assuming there are other values that may have decimals (18.03), do you just want the ".00" removed and not the ".03"?

Comment: @Dbloch - My all values have .00 only.

Comment: @Lamak - That is best to select. I want to update.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since all your values end with ".00", there will be no rounding issues, this will work

```
SELECT CAST(columnname AS INT) AS columnname from tablename
```

to update

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnname = CAST(columnname AS INT)
WHERE .....
```

Comment: But will it replace all value and make it without ZEROs?

Comment: That is what you have asked for, isn't it?  "I want to remove all decimal ZEROS from all values"

Comment: I want to remove .00 from all values.

Comment: Yes it will make "12.00" into "12"

Comment: Yes but your query will select in that manner I mean without .00. I want to update all values in a way that all values become without 00

Comment: See the edited version of the answer, I added an update statement as well

Comment: If the column is a `decimal` with 2 decimal digits, then it will still show the .00, that's a problem with your datatype @rahulbhatt, nothing to do unless that you change the column data type to an INT or a numeric datatype with no decimal digits

Comment: I have updated but still it is same. in database datatype = decimal  , length = 9 and Prec. = 18.

Comment: @rahulbhatt Did you read my previous comment?, if the data type is decimal with a certain number of decimal digits, then the only way to make those disappear would be either in the `SELECT`, or just changing the data type to an INT or a decimal with no decimal digits

Comment: @rahulbhatt As an answer says, it should be the **scale** to 0, setting precision to 0 would mean that you can't save anything there

Answer (score 5):

Here column name must be decimal.

```
select CAST(columnname AS decimal(38,0)) from table
```

Answer (score 4):

As I understand your question, You have one table with column as datatype decimal(18,9).
And the column contains the data as follows:-

```
12.00
15.00
18.00
20.00
```

Now if you want to show record on UI without decimal value means like (12,15,18,20) then there are two options:-

1. Either cast this column as int in Select Clause
2. or may be you want to update this column value like (12,15,18,20).

To apply, First very simple just use the cast in select clause

```
select CAST(count AS INT) from tablename;
```

But if you want to update your column data with int value then you have to update you column datatype

and to do that

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname decimal(9,0)
```

Then execute this

```
UPDATE tablename
   SET count = CAST(columnname AS INT)
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply update with a convert/cast to INT:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET YOUR_COLUMN = CAST(YOUR_COLUMN AS INT)
WHERE -- some condition is met if required
```

Or convert:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET YOUR_COLUMN = CONVERT(INT, YOUR_COLUMN)
WHERE -- some condition is met if required
```

To test you can do this:

```
SELECT YOUR_COLUMN AS CurrentValue,
       CAST(YOUR_COLUMN AS INT) AS NewValue
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you tried to replace the entire 12.00 with '', which isn't going to give your desired results.

Second you are trying to do replace directly on a decimal.   Replace must be performed on a string, so you have to CAST.

There are many ways to get your desired results, but this replace would have worked (assuming your column name is "height":

```
REPLACE(CAST(height as varchar(31)),'.00','')
```

EDIT:

This script works:

```
DECLARE @Height decimal(6,2);
SET @Height = 12.00;
SELECT @Height, REPLACE(CAST(@Height AS varchar(31)),'.00','');
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a decimal data type and you know it will never contain decimal places you can consider setting the **scale** property to 0. For example to `decimal(18, 0)`. This will save you from replacing the `".00"` characters and the query will be faster. In such case, don't forget to to check if the "prevent saving option" is disabled (`SSMS menu "Tools>Options>Designers>Table and database designer>prevent saving changes that require table re-creation"`).

Othewise, you of course remove it using SQL query:

```
select replace(cast([height] as varchar), '.00', '') from table
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data type is DECIMAL with decimal places, say DECIMAL(10,2). The values in your database are 12, 15, 18, and 20.

12 is the same as 12.0 and 12.00 and 12.000 . It is up to the tool you are using to select the data with, how to display the numbers. Yours either defaults to two digits for decimals or it takes the places from your data definition.

If you only want integers in your column, then change its data type to INT. It makes no sense to use DECIMAL then.

If you want integers and decimals in that column then stay with the DECIMAL type. If you don't like the way you are shown the values, then format them in your application. It's up to that client program to decide for instance if to display point or comma for the decimal separator. (The database can be used from different locations.)

Also don't rely on any database or session settings like a decimal separator being a point and not a comma and then use REPLACE on it. That can work for one person and not for the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the floor function.
Example:

```
Select FLOOR(${selectedColumn}) from ${tableName}
```